# How to escape '/' for `SelectFormat` with MessageFormat.js

Tags: escaping, messageformat.js

My `messageFormat` string looks like this: `{foo, select, one/two{1-2} other{3}}`, but `messageFormat` parser throws error because of `/` usage in it.

I have tried, but not working:

```
{foo, select, one'/'two{1-2} other{3}}
{foo, select, 'one/two'{1-2} other{3}}
```

Any ideas?

References:
https://messageformat.github.io/messageformat/
https://messageformat.github.io/messageformat/page-guide#toc3__anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked same question to library's maintainers and got an answer for it. It's not possible right now. Need to find different solution, for example, `one_two`.

[Reference](https://github.com/messageformat/messageformat/issues/268#issuecomment-557533979)